# Join Two networks with different isp

Tags: networking, zyxel

I was asking myself what could I do to join two networks that are in the same building.

the situation is like that:

networkA (office) - RouterA - FirewallA - SwitchesA - PCs
vlan default 1

networkB (guests) - RouterB - FirewallB - SwitchesB - Access_pointsB - Special_PCs and Guest_PCs vlan default 1

suddently There is the necessity to have Special_PCs connect to PCs

I think I could do it with a vpn between the two firewalls, but that might have poor performances.
I think I could do it with a cable connected between the two routers and two static routes but I might have not access to the routers.
Can I probably do it with a cable connected between the lan ports of the two firewalls and policy rules?

All ap firewall and switches are zyxel.

Answer (score 0):

Wire up a link between routers A and B. Route between the nets. Configure security controls such as segmentation and firewalls per your organization's policy and network design.

Once you have a path between the two, B can reach nodes in A's network. That is the primary purpose of routers, and routing protocols.